# Constant curvature surfaces. Revolution of the graphs of solutions to a nonlinear differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have the following differential equation:

$$\pi\cdot\text{y}(x)^2=\sqrt{1+\text{y}'(x)^2}\tag1$$

With the initial condition $\text{y}(0)=1$.

Now, I want to plot the solution in order to obtain the solid of revolution when I rotate the function $\text{y}(x)$ around the x-axis between $0$ and $10$.

> How can I obatin the $3D$-model of that revolution?

Comment: Your initial conditions lead to `(y'[0])^2==-1` which can't be fullfilled for real y!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann true! I edited my question, stupid mistake

Comment: Please explain your ode and show some code if possible.

Comment: This looks familiar... are you looking at constant-curvature surfaces?

Comment: @J.M. yes I am looking at that!

Comment: I see, then you probably should also familiarize yourself with the [Delaunay roulettes](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/delaunay/delaunay.shtml) and the corresponding [nodoids/unduloids](https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/delaunay/delaunay.shtml).

Comment: if so, it is reasonable to reformulate the title accordingly to make the question easily accessible for others,

Comment: @Jan Why didn't you explain in your original post what was your motivation to ask this question? I'm guessing that the existing answers don't satisfy your expectations. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Our purpose is the follolwing graphics:
[image]

The ordinary differential equation at hand can be **solved exactly** in terms of **elliptic functions**.  The solution will be **periodic** (**with singularities**) and so the **numerical approach is not satisfactory** since the **solution cannot be continued past singularity** unless one takes into account basic properties of elliptic functions.

We would like to solve exactly the given differential equation, however working directly with `DSolve` we obtain a solution in an implicit form involving elliptic integrals and so in order to get an **explicit solution** we have to transform  equation appropriately. Rewriting the equation we have:
$${y'(x)}^2-\pi^2 y(x)^4+1=0$$
Working with such a type of equations one can gain an insight to change the dependent variable $y(x) \to w(x)\;$ where $$y(x)=a+\frac{b}{w(x)+c}$$
Our goal is transformig differenial equation for $y(x)$ into canonical Weierstrass form $\;{w'(x)}^2-4w(x)^3+g_2\; w(x)+g_3=0$.

First we find $(a,b,c)$

```
pol = (((c+w[x])^4 /b^2) (y'[x]^2-Pi^2 y[x]^4+1)/.{ y'[x]-> -b w'[x]/(w[x]+c)^2,
         y[x]-> a + b/( w[x]+c)})// Factor // Collect[ #, {w'[x], w[x]}]&;

 cl= Coefficient[ pol, w[x], #]&;
```

Comparing appropriate coefficients with the Weierstras canonical form we have to solve the following system:

```
Solve[{ cl[4] == 0, cl[3] == -4, cl[2] ==0}, {a,b,c}]
```

[image]

For all triples we have the same equation and since we are interested in the real solutions, the both real triples provide an equivalent graphics.

```
With[{ a = 1/Sqrt[Pi], b = Sqrt[Pi], c = -Pi/2},
  ( ((c + w[x])^4 /b^2) (y'[x]^2 - Pi^2 y[x]^4 + 1)/.{ y'[x] ->-b w'[x]/(w[x]+c)^2,
   y[x]-> a + b/(w[x]+c)}) // Factor // Collect[ #, { w'[x], w[x]}]&] == 0
```

> ```
> - Pi^2 w[x] -4 w[x]^3 + w'[x]^2 == 0
> ```

This equation can be solved without prescribing the initial condition

```
 DSolve[- Pi^2 w[x] -4 w[x]^3 + w'[x]^2 == 0, w[x], x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

then we can find `c1` from the initial condition $c_0=y(0)=a+\frac{b}{w(0)+c}$, i.e. let's put `c0=1`

```
c1 = With[{a = 1/Sqrt[Pi], b = Sqrt[Pi], c = -Pi/2, c0 = 1}, 
       InverseWeierstrassP[b/(c0 - a) -c , { -Pi^2, 0}]];
```

and finally the solution of the Cauchy problem `ys[0] == 1` is

```
ys[x_]:= With[{ a = 1/Sqrt[Pi], b = Sqrt[Pi], c = -Pi/2},
          a + b/(WeierstrassP[ x - c1, { -Pi^2, 0}] + c)]

ys[x] // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The solution as an elliptic function is doubly periodic, any period is twice the Weierstrass half-period (there are only two independent periods):

```
wHP = Through @ { WeierstrassHalfPeriodW1, WeierstrassHalfPeriodW2,
                  WeierstrassHalfPeriodW3} @ { -Pi^2, 0}
 N @ %
```

[image]

> ```
>   {0.73966 - 0.73966 I, -1.47933, 0.73966 + 0.73966 I}
> ```

Whenever $x-c_1 = 2 k\; whp_2$ the solution becomes infinite, for $k$ integer and $whp_2$ the real Weierstrass half-period.

Revolution around `x`-axis we can realize with `RevolutionPlot3D`. For better visualization we've restricted  the graphics appropriately and acted with `Re` on the solution (to get rid of possible small imaginary perturbations in elliptic functions, one can also exploit `Chop`).

```
RevolutionPlot3D[ Re @ ys[x], {x,0, 10},
  RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z}, y^2 + z^2 < 4], RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0},
  PlotPoints-> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

The plot at the beginning we obtain with:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[ Re @ ys[x], {x, 0, 10}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0},
  RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z}, y^2 + z^2 <6], PlotPoints -> 60,
  MaxRecursion -> 3, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", BoxRatios->{2,1,1},
  ViewPoint->{ 3/8, -3/2, 1/2}, ImageSize->Large]
```

Answer (score 4):

solve ode

```
Y = NDSolveValue[{(Pi y[x]^2) == Sqrt[ 1 + y'[x]^2] , y[0] == 1 },y, {x, -1, 1}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

Solution is only real for `-.23<x<.42`

revolute around x-axis

```
ParametricPlot3D[ {x, Y[x] Cos[t], Y[x] Sin[t]}, {x, -.3, 1}, {t, 0,2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1} ]
```

[image]

alternativly `RevolutionPlot3D[Y[x], {x, x0, 1}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0},BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]`

Answer (score 1):

Solve this differential-algebraic equation of order $1/2$ with constant boundary condition with the method of separation.

```
pi y^2=Sqrt[1-y'^2]

pi^2y^4=1-y'^2

y'=+/-Sqrt[1-pi^2y^4]

dy/Sqrt[1-pi^2y^4]=+/-dx

x+constant=Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - pi^2 y^4], y]

x+constant=-((I EllipticF[I ArcSin[Sqrt[-pi] y], -1])/Sqrt[-pi])
```

Now there is a unique functional relation between `x` and `y` replace the differential equation.

The boundary condition can be used to make this unique.

But this aim was to get a function `y[x]`.

```
Plot[(-((I EllipticF[I ArcSin[Sqrt[-\[Pi]] y], -1])/
   Sqrt[-\[Pi]])), {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Plot]

The inverse function of the `EllipticF` is the `JacobiAmplitude`.

```
y[x_] := Sin[I JacobiAmplitude[Sqrt[-\[Pi]] I x, -1]]/Sqrt[-\[Pi]] + 1
```

This is a real-valued function!

```
Plot[Sin[I JacobiAmplitude[-Sqrt[-\[Pi]] I x, -1]]/Sqrt[-\[Pi]] + 
  1, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: y[x]]

The resulting surface of rotation is

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 Sin[I JacobiAmplitude[-Sqrt[-\[Pi]] I x, -1]]/Sqrt[-\[Pi]] + 1, {x, 
  0, 1}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: exact solution]

Hope that helps. Have fun.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 Sin[I JacobiAmplitude[-Sqrt[-\[Pi]] I x, -1]]/Sqrt[-\[Pi]] + 1, {x, 
  0, 10}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: result]

Comment: You wrote the DE the wrong way, it has to be $\sqrt{1\color{red}{+}\left(\text{y}'(x)\right)^2}$