# Animate $f(x)$ revolving aroung $Y$ axis

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, animation

I'm asking if there is a way to animate a function $f(x)$ (plotted in a range $(a, b)$ with $a > 0$ and $b > 0$), making it to revolve around the $Y$ axis and showing the solid of revolution obtained in this way.

For example, say $f(x) = 1/x$ in the range $x\in(1, 5)$. I know how to plot the solid of revolution obtained from this, but it's the animation part, if possible, that I would like to understand.

Thank you!

To make things clarer: a code like this would workg well

```
Manipulate[

Show[

ParametricPlot3D[{u^2, 0, u}, {u, 0, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]],

RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}, 
PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5], Specularity[White, 10]}, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
MeshShading -> ms, PlotPoints -> 30]

, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.5}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
ViewPoint -> {1.1, 2.6, 1.73}, ViewVertical -> {1.4, 0.3, 0.2}, 
SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> .4, ImageSize -> 600, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]

, {{ms, None, 
"shades"}, {None -> "NO", {{Red, Yellow}, {Pink, Orange}} ->    "YES"}}
, {{T, 2 Pi}, .001, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
FrameMargins -> 0]
```

Just needs to be adapted to a revolution around $Y$ axis, and to other possible functions.

( Taken from [RevolutionPlot3D: but NOT revolving about the z axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/revolutionplot3d-but-not-revolving-about-the-z-axis) )

Comment: This is closely related (a bit more general issue) [Constant curvature surfaces. Revolution of the graphs of solutions to a nonlinear differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227993/constant-curvature-surfaces-revolution-of-the-graphs-of-solutions-to-a-nonlinea)

Comment: Simply replace "Manipulate" by "Animate"